# Cannot implicitly convert type 'ServiceReference1.Videos[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Videos>

Tags: c#, implicit

I am getting the above error when i call my WCFservice from my web application.

The code is as below

I instantiate my WCF Service:

```
ServiceReference1.VideosClient objService = new ServiceReference1.VideosClient();
```

I create a new instance of my generic collection so i can populate values

```
IList<Videos> videoItem = new List<Videos>();
videoItem =  objService.GetVideoDetailsById(id);
txtTitle.Text = videoItem[0].Title.ToString(); ;
txtDescription.Text = videoItem[0].Description.ToString();
txtRentalPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(videoItem[0].RentalPrice);
```

However when I call the `GetVideoDetailsByID` method of the service I get the error message

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'ServiceReference1.Videos[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList

I have gone through some similar posts but cant seem to find a solution for my problem.
My service reference properties shows that my collection type is `System.Collection.Generic.List`

Please help.
Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At face value it would seem that the `GetVideoDetailsById()` method is returning an array, have you tried changing your code to something like:

```
Videos[] videoItem;
videoItem =  objService.GetVideoDetailsById(id);
```

Or, to make it really easy, just collapse to a single line and use `var`

```
 var videoItem =  objService.GetVideoDetailsById(id);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. If i use var vid =  objService.GetVideoDetailsById(id); how do i then get the specific items returned by the method.For example i want to get the Description  returned by the method call

Comment: Assuming it's returning an array, then the rest of your code should work as-is.